# Reference Frame confusion

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames

I am trying to work through the calculation in a particular paper (Smith & Will, Phys. Rev. D 22, 1276 (1980)). My GR is a little rusty, but I have a half-decent background in it. In any case, on the second page of the paper (column 2 paragraph 2), it reads "The most convenient choice is a freely falling observer, located at the test particle, instantaneously at rest with respect to it." Does this mean that the observer is in the particles rest frame, or simply at rest with respect to it only at the time of measurement? Or neither...?

Comment: It's like the observer is riding that test particle, which is free falling. So the particle is at rest in his RF.

Comment: Thank you. Just so I'm extra clear, what then is the difference between the observer being in the particles RF and the particle being in the observers RF?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with this question. The particle by itself is in no reference frame, it is moving through spacetime. To describe the physics and understand what happens we need reference frames and coordinates, so we can pick the reference frame we want, and put the observer where we want. So we put the observer in the RF of the particle, we can't force the particle to be in a prefixed RF, cause we would forcing physics. "The particle is where the physics tells her to be and does what the physics tells her to do". I hope i got the point of your question.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. This is just a difficult question to ask, since simple topics such as these aren't really explained well in classes I've taken as they are assumed to just be understood. Your answer is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot access the paper full text right now, but from the title and the abstract it is quite clear that the charged test particle is at rest in the Schwarzschild black hole spacetime, while the observer is "in a local, freely falling frame momentarily at rest with respect to the charge". So the charge is at rest in the observer frame only very briefly ("momentarily"). The observer is freely falling, while the charge is fixed. You can achieve this by throwing the observer vertically up like a stone. She decelerates while she ascends and stops as she reaches the charge. Then she starts descending again like...a stone.

Caveat: I have not read the paper